# Flask API returns BAD REQUEST when trying to post from a unittest

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

Im trying to write an API unit test that checks whether data was inserted successfully to a db.
Below is my unit test:

```
    def test_api_can_create_request(self):
    """Test api can create a request"""
    res = self.client().post('/api/v1/user/', data= self.newRecord)
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 201)
```

This is the setUp method which also defines the newRecord object that is used in the test method

```
    def setUp(self):
    """Declare test variables and initialize app."""
    self.app = create_app(config_filename=app_config['testing'])
    self.client = self.app.test_client
    self.newRecord = {'id': 11, 'requestor':'Alicia Keys', 'type': 'maintenance',
    'status':'Approved', 'desc': 'Description goes here'}
```

This is the class that handles the post method for creating new records in the db:

```
class RequestResource(Resource):
"""Get all request"""
def get(self):     
    return dtrequest, 200

"""create new request"""
def post(self):
    json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
    if not json_data:
        return {'message': 'No input data provided'}, 400
    dtrequest.append(json_data)
    return {"status":"success", "data": json_data }, 201
```

But I get the following error when trying to test this method:
[image]

Comment: What you have there doesn't look like it'd work *normally*...if you load this endpoint up and hit it, do you get something similar?

Comment: If I hit it on Postman it works quite fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you're posting a literal dictionary to your route, instead of converting it to json first. So try:

```
import json
res = self.client().post('/api/v1/user/', data= json.dumps(self.newRecord))
```